# Grouping by list items in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data structure that is set up as follows:
`

```
"id":"12345",
"key":"XYZ-123"
"fields":{
    "labels":[
        "label1",
        "label2",
        "label3"
     ]
 },
"id":"67890",
"key":"ABS-789"
"fields":{
    "labels":[
        "label1",
        "label2",
     ]
 }
```

`

I am using pandas to put them in a dataframe, and what I need to do is get the number of entries that have a certain label. Using the code above, my ideal output would be

    `label1: 2
    label2: 2
    label3: 1`

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.
EDIT - One of the things I have tried is flattening the dataframe further, so that columns are output as label_1, label_2, label_3 and so on. However, there is duplicate data between the columns.

Comment: It is usually not welcome just to ask for solutions here. You should show your work and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way via `collections.Counter`. My assumption is you begin with a list of dictionaries, as defined below.

```
lst = [{"id":"12345","key":"XYZ-123","fields":{"labels":["label1", "label2", "label3"]}},
       {"id":"67890","key":"ABS-789","fields":{"labels":["label1","label2",]}}]

# [{'fields': {'labels': ['label1', 'label2', 'label3']},
#   'id': '12345',
#   'key': 'XYZ-123'},
#  {'fields': {'labels': ['label1', 'label2']}, 'id': '67890', 'key': 'ABS-789'}]

from collections import Counter

c = Counter(el for d in lst for el in d['fields']['labels'])

df = pd.DataFrame(sorted(c.items()), columns=['label', 'count'])

#     label  count
# 0  label1      2
# 1  label2      2
# 2  label3      1
```

Comment: If you're going to go that approach - I'd suggest skipping defaultdict and go straight to `collections.Counter`, eg: `Counter(el for d in lst for el in d['fields']['labels'])` - at that point - it's somewhat debatable whether one really does need a dataframe from that...

Comment: @JonClements, good point. Dataframe conversion is, of course, an optional final step.

Comment: If you wanted to up front frame it - I'd take a guess that `df = pd.DataFrame({**d.pop('fields'), **d} for d in lst)` and then shaping as necessary for `.value_counts()` or similar or even `df['labels'].apply(Counter).sum()` would work...